# How can I find the Amazon FPS fee assessed for a transaction?

Tags: amazon-fps

My application uses Amazon FPS to charge a user. After setting up a pipeline and receiving a token, I then issue a Pay request with that token. The response contains a Transaction ID and a Transaction Status.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSAdvancedGuide/Pay.html

Then I wait to receive an Instant Payment Notification, which has several fields, including the total transaction amount.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSAdvancedGuide/APPNDX_IPN.html

For this transaction, Amazon FPS subtracts a fee from the money my account receives. I need to record the fee for the application's bookkeeping.

Where can I find the amount of this fee?

I could attempt to calculate it, but with rounding that seems error-prone. Additionally, Amazon's fee schedule varies with scale: higher-volume applications are charged lower rates. Attempting to reproduce that math accurately sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSAPIReference/AWSFPSIPNDetails.html), no fee information is sent in an IPN - as you've discovered.

The only way to get the transaction fee is to call [GetTransaction](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSAPIReference/GetTransaction.html). This call returns a [TransactionDetail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSAPIReference/TransactionDetail.html) which has an `FPSFees` property.

Comment: Oh, FFS. I've been looking at the "Advanced Quick Start", which is exactly as detailed and looks almost exactly the same, but doesn't list all of the API calls. (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSAdvancedGuide/GetTransactionStatus.html) Thank you. :)

Comment: Yeah, it can be a little confusing at first. Amazon has broken up the API's _documentation_ into categories that they felt would be the most helpful for users getting started - but there's only one API in the end.